# Providing Coded-UI support for VS2012,2013,2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have successfully implemented the Coded UI support for my custom control in VS2010. But when i try to upgrade those projects to VS2012, VS2013, or VS2015, the following exception has occurred. Please find the exception stack trace below:

**Sample code:**

```
if (uiTestControl.ControlType == ControlType.Table)
{
    //To-Do
}
```

**Exception:**

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ControlType'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyInternal[T](String propertyName)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.get_ControlType()
       at CustomControl.GetPropertyNames(UITestControl uiTestControl) in d:\Coded_UI_Source\Src\CustomExtensionProvider\CustomPropertyProvider.cs:line 94
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ALUtility.GetProperties(UITestPropertyProvider provider, UITestControl uiControl, UITestPropertyAttributes attributes, UITestPropertyAttributes ignoreAttributes)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetReadableAndAssertablePropertyNames()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CodedUITest.Controls.UIControlLocator.UIControlFinder.FetchProperties(UITestControl element)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CodedUITest.Controls.UIControlLocator.UIControlFinder.PopulateUITestControlDetails(UITestControl element, UIControlDetails uiControlDetails)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CodedUITest.Controls.UIControlLocator.UIControlFinder.CaptureControl(UITestControl element)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CodedUITest.Controls.UIControlLocator.UIControlFinder.PlaybackThreadproc()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Please help me to overcome this issue and also please let me know whether i need to do anything to support in VS2012, 2013 and 2015.

Comment: Exception clearly says that you cannot compare `string` with `ControlType`. Are you sure that what you have in `uiTestControl.ControlType` is a standard UITestControl with a standard `ControlType` of type `ControlType`?

Comment: My issue is that, that code is perfectly working in VS2010, but it is not working in 2012,2013,2015 and it throws above exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occours in your code CustomPropertyProvider.cs:line 94, it is calling the get_ControlType() which is looking from control type. It seems you haven't set the control type correctly in the custom control when it tries to convert the name of the controltype into a Type.

```
 at CustomControl.GetPropertyNames(UITestControl uiTestControl) in d:\Coded_UI_Source\Src\CustomExtensionProvider\CustomPropertyProvider.cs:line 94
```

Comment: Yes. I analyzed those thing and i wonder that it is working in VS2010 and not working in VS2012. that's why

Comment: Maybe there is a update in the version of the controls/tooling. Microsoft did some changes/updates to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.

Comment: Thanks..i have posted query in MSDN also...But i want to know whether anyone know or face this kind of issue...